# How to read Retention Label applied column using REST API or CAML query

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, caml

I am trying to read Retention Label applied  using REST API but unable to read tried both values, tried CAML as well but not getting this field, can we read using API or is not possible?

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('documents')/items?$Select=OData__ComplianceTagWrittenTime
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('documents')/items?$Select=_ComplianceTagWrittenTime
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use **FieldValuesAsText** to get the Value. But this only works on a single item

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('documents')/items(id)/FieldValuesAsText
```

Comment: it only work for one item right but i have to get iterate for all items

Comment: i tired your way and able to read data by looping in Thanks for your solution it worked however need to iterate logic , but thats developer life

Answer (score 0):

Is the Graph API an option for you? You could do this with the following call:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/lists/{id}/items?$expand=fields($select=id,_ComplianceTagWrittenTime)
```

Comment: graph api i cannot use any other option we have